# XSLT Transformation using Ajax works well in Chrome crashes with strange Error in Mozilla and Edge

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, xslt, nginx

```
window.jQuery(document).on('click', '#seeDetails', function() {
var propertyId = $(this).data('id');  
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        try { xhr.responseType = "msxml-document"; } catch(err){}
    },
    url: 'http://stu-nginx.cms.gre.ac.uk/~pa426/SowaCw/searchCombined.php',
    data: {
       propertyId : propertyId
    },
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(resultXml, status, xhr){
        xml = resultXml;

        $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            try { xhr.responseType = "msxml-document"; } catch(err){}
        },
        url: 'http://stu-nginx.cms.gre.ac.uk/~pa426/SowaCw/cwlistSinglePropStyle.xsl',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(resultXsl, status, xhr){

            xsl = resultXsl;
            console.log(xml);
            console.log(xsl);

            try{ 

               if (window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window)
                {

                    var xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0");
                    xmldoc.async = false;
                    xmldoc.load(xml);

                    var xsldoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.3.0");
                    xsldoc.async = false;
                    xsldoc.load(xsl);

                    ex = xmldoc.transformNode(xsldoc);
                    document.getElementById("contact").innerHTML = ex;
                }
                // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
                else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
                {
                    xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
                    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
                    resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);//Mozilla Err 
                    document.getElementById("contact").appendChild(resultDocument);    
                }


                if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                  deselect($(this));
                  document.getElementById("contact").innerHTML = '';
                } else {
                  $(this).addClass('selected');
                  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle();
                }

            }catch(e){console.log(e)}
        }
    });
    }
});
});
```

The error in the console from Firefox:
Exception { message: "", result: 2153775121, name: "", filename: "http://stu-nginx...", lineNumber: 58, columnNumber: 0, data: null, stack: ".success/<.success@http://stu-nginx..." }

The error in the console from EDGE:
[object Error]{description: "No such interface supported", message: "No such interface supported", name: "Error", number: -2147467262, stack: "Error: No s..."}

XSL declaration:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="//property">`

Comment: Do the statements `console.log(xml);` and `console.log(xsl);` show what you expect in Edge and Firefox when the error occurs? Which error does Edge give you exactly?

Comment: And which is line 58 exactly respectively which statement gives the error if you take out the try/catch?

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you for you interest.

Comment: Line 58 is when I import the stylesheet xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl); The console log returns the expected value. I am sorry I can't give you the exception from edge right now because the project it's on a private network I can access it tomorrow and I will update you but it's really similar to the Mozilla exception.